# Оптимизирующий компилятор Microsoft Visual и OpenGL

Tags: c, visual-studio, ассемблер, компиляция

Открыв Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt и соответственно открыв свой проект, пытаюсь запустить его используя следующее :

```
cl /S -o test.s Main.cpp
```

Но компилятор не знает о том,что такое /S.

```
cl: командная строка warning D9002: пропуск неизвестного параметра "/S"
```

Как же тогда получить ассемблерный листинг программы?
UPD:
Исправил на это`cl /FA -o test.s Main.cpp`
, но не могу увидеть ассемблерный листинг, выводит такое
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Понял,расширение должно быть .cod

Comment: Так а откуда вообще взялось `/S`? И при чем здесь OpenGL?

Answer (score 0):

Генерация ассемблерного листинга в компиляторе MSVC активируется опциями `/FA`, `/FAc`, `/FAs` и т.п. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/367y26c6.aspx). Никакого `/S`.

Comment: ,перепутал с gcc